# Change SeriesChartType color like Window task manager

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

I want to changed my `Chart control SeriesChartType` but currently after changing the color effects for all the graph include the `Margins` I end up with this:

[image]

And I am looking for something that looks like the *Windows Task Manager*

[image]

Can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try customising something like this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    //Add an area chart to go under your line series
    Chart1.Series.Add("UnderSeries")
    Chart1.Series(0).BorderWidth = Chart1.Series(0).BorderWidth + 2
    Chart1.Series("UnderSeries").ChartType = SeriesChartType.Area

    //To create a semi transparent color, set alpha to 127. 
    //To create a transparent color, set alpha to any value from 1 through 254.
    Chart1.Series("UnderSeries").Color = Color.FromArgb(127, Color.Aqua)

    //place area chart over your line
    For Each pt As DataPoint In Chart1.Series(0).Points
        Chart1.Series("UnderSeries").Points.AddXY(pt.XValue, pt.YValues(0))
    Next

    //reorder series so line is above area chart
    Dim topSeries As Series = Chart1.Series(0)
    Chart1.Series.Remove(topSeries)
    Chart1.Series.Add(topSeries)

End sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually you could look at

```
seriesTotal.BorderColor = Color.YourColor;
seriesTotal.BorderWidth = 1;
```